# I have an exception in connection to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>



<table>
<%
try
{

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbname","username","password");

Statement statement = con.createStatement() ; 

ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select FileName_WO_Ext  from dbo.ALLOTMENT WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);") ;


while(resultset.next())
{
String datee =resultset.getString("FileName_WO_Ext ");
out.println(datee);
}
}
catch(SQLException ex){
System.out.println("exception--"+ex);

}

%>
</table>
```

this is my code the eroor i am getting is

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /second.jsp at line 164

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /second.jsp at line 164

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /second.jsp at line 164

161: <%

162: try

163: {

164:    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

165: 

166: 

167: Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/CubeHomeTrans","sa","softex");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.second_jsp._jspService(second_jsp.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.second_jsp._jspService(second_jsp.java:252)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.67 logs.
```

Comment: make sure jdbc driver is in lib folder

Comment: i have the sql jdbc driver jar file in the lib folder

Comment: Then this lib is not loaded

Answer (score -1):

I managed to clear the error after

- I removed the jar file from `lib`,
- And added it once again to the `build path` and the `lib` folder in the `WEB-INF`,
- Finally, I ran the program again.